# Использование @Value в Spring

Tags: java, spring

Пытаюсь получить данные из файла `application.properties` находящегося в корне `resources` таки образом:

```
@Component
public class TestSpAn {
    @Getter
    @Value("${test.a.b}")
    String val;
}
```

В `application.properties` это выглядит так:

```
test.a.b=12345
```

Вызываю вот так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringBeansConfigurationInjector.class);
    final TestSpAn bean = context.getBean(TestSpAn.class);
    System.out.println(bean.getVal());
}
```

Вывод в консоль вместо `12345`, получаю `${test.a.b}`.

Подскажите пожалуйста почему так происходит, и как это исправить?

Вот такие модули спринга подключены:

```
    ...
    <spring-version>4.3.9.RELEASE</spring-version>
    ...

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> application.properties

Автоматически подключается в Spring Boot приложении, но так как у вас, не Spring Boot, вам необходимо явно подключить property файл. Делается это при помощи аннотации:

> @PropertySource

В вашем классе

> SpringBeansConfigurationInjector

добавьте следующее :

> @PropertySource("aplication.properties")

или

> @PropertySource("classpath:/путь_до_файла")

Comment: я правильно Вас понял что в SpringBeansConfigurationInjector надо аннотировать класс а не методы?

Comment: @Pavel немного не понял вашего вопроса. Если вас интересует, на что вешается аннотация PropertySource, то на класс.

Answer (score 0):

Всё, что нужно - это иметь в контексте бин типа [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html). Если у вас xml-конфигурация, то для этого есть специальный тег:

```
<context:property-placeholder
    location="classpath:META-INF/application.properties" />
```

А если java-конфигурация, то поможет аннотация `@PropertySource`, как уже написал @aleshka-batman